# Condition Butterworth polynomial

Tags: polynomials, signal-processing, transfer-theory

My course states that a polynomial is a Butterworth polynomial when it satisfies the following condition:

$|B(j\Omega)|=\sqrt {1+{\Omega}^{2\,n}}=\sqrt {1+{(\omega/\omega_p)}^{2\,n}}$

I'm really into accepting this, without having a lead why they use the modulus, to specify the requirements in the first place. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The modulus is there because $B$ is complex valued. Are you asking why the gain of a butterworth filter has the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\omega^{2n}}}$?

Comment: @Batman, no I'm wondering why the imaginary part has to be in of the ^(2n) order. Has this perhaps something to do with the poles on the unit circle?

Comment: If you have an order $n$ filter with transfer function $H(j \omega)$, the gain is given by $|H(j \omega)| =  H(j \omega) H^*(j \omega)$. Note that you're multiplying the frequency response by its conjugate for this, so if you have a degree n polynomial, it will double the degree.

Comment: @Batman, Ohyeah okay. I completely forgot the fact of multiplying by it's conjugate ! Thanks!